# neo4j 2.1.8 HA in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I have the following Problem:

I want to set up 3 neo4j-servers in EC2. All neo4j servers are on the same VPC-Network

The configuration of each neo4j server is as follows:

**neo4j-Master:**

*conf/neo4j-server.properties*

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=110.0.0.5
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7484
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
```

*conf/neo4j.properties*

```
ha.server_id=1
ha.initial_hosts=110.0.0.5:5001,110.0.1.5:5001,110.0.2.5:5001
ha.cluster_server=110.0.0.5:5001
ha.server=110.0.0.5:6001
```

**neo4j-Slave-1:**

*conf/neo4j-server.properties*

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=110.0.1.5
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7475
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7485
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
```

*conf/neo4j.properties*

```
ha.server_id=2
ha.initial_hosts=110.0.0.5:5001,110.0.1.5:5001,110.0.2.5:5001
ha.cluster_server=110.0.1.5:5001
ha.server=110.0.1.5:6001
```

**neo4j-Slave-2:**

*conf/neo4j-server.properties*

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=110.0.2.5
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7476
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7486
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
```

*conf/neo4j.properties*

```
ha.server_id=3
ha.initial_hosts=110.0.0.5:5001,110.0.1.5:5001,110.0.2.5:5001
ha.cluster_server=110.0.2.5:5001
ha.server=110.0.2.5:6001
```

And after trying to start the neo4j-server(Master) the following warning is given:

```
2015-09-21 12:02:45.964+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Write transactions to database disabled
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are those server accessible from one to others?

Comment: yes, it is accessible.

Comment: Could you please provide log files? messages.log and console.log?

Comment: You don't need to have webserver.port and webserver.https.port on the different port if your Neo4j are on different machines.